# Environment specific prompt when migrating or seeding in Laravel/Artisan

Tags: laravel, seeding, migrating, laravel-artisan

I like that Artisan will prompt me before running potentially destructive operations like migrating and seeding on **production** and I'm wondering if there's any way for me to get that functionality in other environments, such as staging. For example, if I run `php artisan migrate` it will output:

```
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

Do you really wish to run this command?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put APP_ENV=production in your .env file, it should show that message. I would think that's the main purpose of the APP_ENV unless you using the "local" environment for other purposes as well which you don't want happening in production.